# Working on solving an Nqueens problem with backtracking and as a CSP specifically most constrained value

Tags: c++, n-queens

So I am currently working on a project to place N queens on an NxN board and prevent them from attacking each other.  This project is for an intro level AI course.  It has a few specific criteria to get full points which are, finding up to 3 solutions for any board size up to N = 100 in 5 seconds or less.  I'm currently trying to make this a constraint satisfaction problem by choosing the most constrained row which if I understand it correctly will prevent rows that are closer to fully attacked from getting there.

Initially the user will input a column number and a queen will be placed in that column on the first row of the board.  From there the attack board will be updated using that row column combination by increasing the value of all diagonals and the row and column a small example of the former and the latter below

```cpp
        void main()
    {
        int size, row, col;
        row = 1;
        cout << "Enter the board size: ";
        cin >> size;
        cout << "Enter column of first queen: ";
        cin >> col;

        cols[row] = col; // cols store the column value of each queen in that particular row.
        updateAttack(row, col, +1, size);
        findNextQueen(size);

        // return here if we found all the solution
        //cout << solutionCount << " solutions found. see NQueen.out.\n";
        cout << solutionCount << " solutions found. see NQueen.out.\n";
        fout.close();
        system("pause");
    }
```

```cpp
void updateAttack(int r, int c, int change, int size)       // Updates the attack board given the location a queen being placed
{
    int r1, c1;

    // update diagnals
    for (r1 = r - 1, c1 = c - 1; r1 >= 1 && c1 >= 1; r1--, c1--)
        attack[r1][c1] += change;

    for (r1 = r + 1, c1 = c + 1; r1 <= size && c1 <= size; r1++, c1++)
        attack[r1][c1] += change;

    for (r1 = r - 1, c1 = c + 1; r1 >= 1 && c1 <= size; r1--, c1++)
        attack[r1][c1] += change;

    for (r1 = r + 1, c1 = c - 1; r1 <= size && c1 >= 1; r1++, c1--)
        attack[r1][c1] += change;

    // update columns 
    for (r1 = 1, c1 = c; r1 <= size; r1++) // k goes to each row          
        attack[r1][c1] += change;
}
```

The main issue with this program is choosing which row to place the queen in.  In a simple backtracking method with recursive calls of the queen placing you increment down the rows and place the queen in the first space in that row that isn't currently under attack and then doing the same for the next row and the next queen until the queen cannot be placed, in which case you backtrack and attempt to fix the previous queen by moving it to the next spot.  An example of this being done with backtracking and no CSP implemented below.

```
    void findNextQueen(int r, int size)
{
      for (int c=1;c<=size;c++)
      {
        if (attack[r][c]==0) // not under attack
        {   
            cols[r]=c;  // assign another queen
            if (r<size)
            {
                updateAttack(r,c,+1, size);
                findNextQueen(r+1, size);
                updateAttack(r,c, -1, size);
            }
            else
            {
                print1solution(size);
                if (solutionCount >= 3)
                {
                    cout << solutionCount << " solutions found. see NQueen.out.\n";
                    system("pause");
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
      }
    return;
}
```

The constraint satisfaction attempts to solve a problem caused during this backtracking where you might later on completely fill rows below with attack values which will cause alot of backtracking to be required increasing the time it takes by alot of time.  It does this by attempting to choose rows that have more spaces being attacked first in order to prevent them from being lost and requiring the late backtracking.  My example of this that is causing the issues, currently that it always seems to come to 0 solutions possible below.

```
void findNextQueen(int size)
{
    int bestRowCount = 0;
    int bestRow = 2;

    for (int r = 2; r <= size; r++)         // Meant to find the most constrained row and use that as my r value for attack array
    {

            int aRowCount = 0;      // Count of attacks in current row
            for (int c = 1; c <= size; c++)
            {
                if (attack[r][c] >= 1)
                {
                    aRowCount++;
                }
            }
            if ((aRowCount > bestRowCount) && (aRowCount != size))
            {
                bestRowCount = aRowCount;
                bestRow = r;
            }
    }
    for (int c = 1; c <= size; c++)
    {
        if (attack[bestRow][c] == 0) // not under attack
        {
            cols[bestRow] = c;  // assign another queen
            if (queensLeft(size) == 1)  // returns true if there are rows that still lack a queen
            {
                updateAttack(bestRow, c, +1, size);
                findNextQueen(size);
                cols[bestRow] = 0;
                updateAttack(bestRow, c, -1, size);
            }
            else
            {
                print1solution(size);
                if (solutionCount >= 3)
                {
                    cout << solutionCount << " solutions found. see NQueen.out.\n";
                    system("pause");
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this problem. Is it possible to deadlock yourself at turns N+1, N+2, etc if you choose the wrong combination of placements at turns N, N-1, etc?

Comment: What you are inputting in the size? 64 or 8?

Comment: It would really help if the problem would be more highlighted/explained or even better - visualized. Also, by breaking the code in smaller peaces would also help others to understand the underlying logic.

Comment: Also, not sure if there's currently a problem with the code? Are you getting the correct results? You're exceeding that stack sometimes (not clear if that's still happening). Is there a problem? You're looking for performance improvements, etc...

Comment: Can you actually explain in words what each of your function is doing? I see some recursion going on, but cannot follow your code as written.

Comment: For the code review use [CodeReview StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and study this articles [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm going to try to edit this question to try to better explain what is going on, but to be clear the code isn't doing what I'm expecting so i don't know if that disqualifies me from asking.

Comment: So i edited my post a bit and tried explaining the mindset behind various parts of the program as well as added a few extra comments in the code snippets where i thought appropriate, to address a comment that i saw i feel like this is either very close to what im trying to accomplish but i can't seem to pinpoint where exactly im making an error

Answer (score 0):

The very similar problem was introduced in LeetCode:

https://leetcode.com/problems/n-queens-ii

You can go to discussions and find explanation with code solutions.
You will need to modify code to return possible results when you reach your limit.